# JPA Entity as JSF Bean?

Tags: jsf, entity, backing-beans

Does it make sense to use Entities as JSF Backing Beans?

```
@Entity
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class User {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    @EJB
    private UserService service;

    public void submit() {
        service.create(this);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Or is it better to keep them separately and transfer the data from the backing bean to the entity at the end?

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserBean {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    @EJB
    private UserService service;

    public void submit() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstname(firstname);
        user.setLastname(lastname);
        service.create(user);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You *could* do so. It's technically possible. But it does (design)functionally not make any sense. You're basically tight-coupling the model with the controller. Usually the JPA entity (model) is a property of a JSF managed bean (controller). This keeps the code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You don't want to duplicate the same properties over all place, let alone annotations on those such as bean validation constraints.

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Register {

    private User user;

    @EJB
    private UserService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { 
        user = new User();
    }

    public void submit() {
        service.create(user);
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

}
```

with this Facelets page (view):

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{register.user.email}" />
    <h:inputSecret value="#{register.user.password}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{register.user.firstname}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{register.user.lastname}" />
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{register.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

#### See also:

- [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)
- [JSF Controller, Service and DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao/)
- [Contradictory explanations of MVC in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757126/contradictory-explanations-of-mvc-in-jsf/)
- [JSF 2 reusing the validation defined in the JPA entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374009/jsf-2-reusing-the-validation-defined-in-the-jpa-entities/)
- [why shouldn't entity bean be managed by JSF framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431338/why-shouldnt-entity-bean-be-managed-by-jsf-framework/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to have a good design. Is your answer a sample of a good design or answer to my question or both? Which design would you suggest for a JSF JPA project as a GURU.:-)

Comment: It's both. I would usually not answer/recommend wrong designs at all.

Comment: Do u think that is a great idea to expose an Entity directly in Bean class?

Comment: This design is the simplest one, but it will hold references to the entityManager (at least with eclipselink), which in turn will hold the identityMap. How to deal with this?