# JSF coding technique: Advantages of working with fields or object directly behind form?

Tags: jsf

Let's assume I have an object of the following `User` class:

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

A corresponding JSF form might look as A)

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel for="userName" />
    <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{userController.user.name}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{userController.saveUserObject}" />
</h:form>
```

or as B)

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel for="userName" />
    <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{userController.name}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{userController.saveUser}" />
</h:form>
```

The corresponding `UserController` class might look as follows:

```
@ViewScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {
    // User object
    private User user;

    // User name field
    private String name;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
         this.user = new User();
    }

    public void saveUser() {
         User user = new User();
         user.setName(name);
         // Save user to database
    }

    public void saveUserObject() {
        // Save user to database
        // User object is already created and contains the given "name" value via POST
    }
}
```

The essential difference is that A) directly works with the `User` object whereas B) needs to construct the `User` object manually and set the field(s) accordingly.

One strong advantage for me is that A) encapsulates the `User` object directly and that you do not need to transform the form values into a `User` object. This seems to save code and looks more object-orientated.

Are there any other advantages in using A) over B) you might come up with? How is it done in real-life code, especially when using more recent JSF versions such as 2.2?

Comment: I don't think the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301363/jpa-entity-as-jsf-bean) is a duplicate. That one asks about using domain entities *as* backing beans; this one asks about whether the view should deal *only* with the backing bean, or if it should access domain objects stored in the backing been directly.