# Modal edit dialog on Primefaces with JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, modal-dialog, crud

I'm trying to create some CRUD JSF application with edit/new screen implemented as a modal dialog. The problem is that I can't find a way how to make new and edit operation done by this dialog performed with ajax. With delete all was very simple (just ajax="true" option).

Here is a code of button which is used to show the dialog

```
<h:form id="dataForm">
        <div class="ui-g">    
            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-9">
                <p:dataGrid var="product" value="#{products.productList}" columns="3" layout="grid"
                            rows="12" paginator="true" id="products"
                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="6,12,16">

                    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{products.preloadProductList}" />

                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Products
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:panel header="#{product.name}" style="text-align:center">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">

                            <h:outputText value="#{product.name}"/>

                            <h:outputText value="#{product.price}"/>

                            <%-- Here new/edit dialog window is opened --%>
                            <p:commandLink update=":dataForm:productDetail" oncomplete="PF('productDialog').show()">
                                Edit
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{product}" target="#{products.product}"/>
                            </p:commandLink>

                            <p:commandLink update=":dataForm" action="#{products.deleteAction(product)}" ajax="true">
                                Delete
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>

                </p:dataGrid>

                <ui:include src="WEB-INF/dialogs/edit_product.xhtml"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

Here is dialog window which is moved to separete file edit_product.xhtml

```
<ui:composition
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <p:dialog header="Product Info" widgetVar="productDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
              hideEffect="fade"
              resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="productDetail" style="text-align:center;">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{not empty products.product}"
                         columnClasses="label,value">

                <h:outputText value="Id:"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{products.id}"/>

                <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{products.name}"/>

                <h:outputText value="Price"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{products.price}"/>
            </p:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{products.saveProduct}"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is Managed bean which is used by the Product dataGrid and dialog window.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "products")
@SessionScoped
public class ProductsBean {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductsBean.class);

    @Inject
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    private Product product;

    private Collection<Product> productList;

    public void preloadProductList(ComponentSystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        productList = productRepository.getAll();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return String.valueOf(product.getId());
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        product.setId(Long.valueOf(id));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return product.getName();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        product.setName(name);
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return product.getPrice();
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        product.setPrice(price);
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return this.product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public Collection<Product> getProductList() {
        logger.info("Get product list");
        return productList;
    }

    public void newProductAction() {
        this.product = new Product();
    }

    public void deleteAction(Product product) {
        logger.info("Delete product");
        productRepository.remove(product);
    }

    public void saveProduct() {
        productRepository.merge(product);
    }
}
```

No matter if I add ajax option or not the whole window is reloaded after Save button is pressed. Could you show me the right direction for the implementation, please?

P.S. If you need more code to answer you can find it here:

- Main page with Product table https://github.com/usharik/GeekBrainsJavaEE/blob/master/lesson5-jpa/src/main/webapp/index.xhtml
- Edit/New dialog https://github.com/usharik/GeekBrainsJavaEE/blob/master/lesson5-jpa/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dialogs/edit_product.xhtml

Comment: Hi Alexey. It is common practice in StackOverflow to create a [mcve] and post that inline in the question. I did not downvote (yet), but please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I expected something like that. Will try to fix it ASAP.

Comment: Hi, read the links about [mcve] again and also read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. This is not a [mcve]. On one hand there is way to much code now (it is not 'minimal') and on the other hand there is code missing (it is not complete in the sence that copy/paste of the code above into a new clean project fails to run (not executable)

Comment: Just removed some not necessary code and add the Managed Bean into question. Will try to make it more suitable but I need time for that. Hope for your understanding.

Comment: Sure I understand, but next time it is better to all this upfront. Saves us time asking for it (and getting frustrated since very little people do it upfront). But still, you can remove lots and lots of code.  And please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301363/jpa-entity-as-jsf-bean you have lots of 'code duplication regarding getting and setting product values.

Comment: You mean not to duplicate getters and setters for entities in managed bean? If yes I'm just working on refactoring of that. For some reasons lot of examples are writen this way.

Comment: Correct, lots of blogs and semi-commercial (getting clicks for the adds) are not that good. On the JSF info pages are some good ones and https://jsf.zeef.com  (by the famous BalusC) has some too. And buying his JSF 2.3 book is something I can advice, it is good (and btw you seem to be using jsf managed beans which are already deprecated, better use CDI managed ones)

Comment: Looks like I found there the problem is. I'm using not Primefaces but standard JSF button in the dialog. Namespace was wrong.